# What is the sum of all integers a such that $a^2-7a-7$ divided by $a-4$ yields an integer?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, integers

I sat down for several minutes over the span of a few days to try to solve this problem. I tried different methods, however, the only method I could devise was about making a well educated guess! I really want to find out the real solution to the problem.

Comment: Several minutes is probably not sufficient. What happens if you do the division (Long Division or Synthetic Division) of $a^2-7a-7$ by $a-4$?

Comment: @MathNoob What exactly have you tried? Maybe you can start by noting that
$$ \dfrac{a^2-7a-7}{a-4} = a-3-\frac{19}{a-4}$$

Comment: @pierrecarre you made it 23+5-15+3? ✌️

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{a^2 - 7a - 7}{a - 4} = \frac{a^2 - 4a}{a - 4} - \frac{3a + 7}{a - 4} = a - \frac{3a - 12 + 19}{a - 4} = a - \frac{3a - 12}{a - 4} - \frac{19}{a - 4} = a - 3 - \frac{19}{a - 4}$. $a - 3$ is an integer whenever $a$ is an integer. Hence, you need the integers $a$ such that $\frac{19}{a - 4}$ is an integer.

$\frac{19}{a - 4}$ is an integer if and only if $a - 4$ divides $19$. $19$ has divisors $\{-19, -1, 1, 19\}$, hence $a \in \{-15, 3, 5, 23\}$. The sum of the elements of $\{-15, 3, 5, 23\}$ is $16$.

Comment: Thank you so much! It was so helpful!